# How to check missing dependencies of an uninstalled rpm in an iso

Tags: centos, rpm, iso

I am trying to find the missing dependencies of an uninstalled rpm of an iso. I am unable to find any command that listing me missing dependencies of an uninstalled rpm. Any help from your side would be great.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use rpm -Vp --nofiledigest foo*.rpm to check dependencies against the system /var/lib/rpm database.

Create an alternative "everything" rpmdb that contains all possible package headers and use --dbpath /some/other/rpmdb more generally.

The "everything" rpm db can be created with rpm -Uvh --dbpath /some/other/rpmdb --justdb --noscripts --notriggers *.rpm (assuming all *.rpm packages of interest are in the current directory). You can also create a manifest: a file of paths to all *.rpm packages.